# How to import two pr2 on gazebo at the same time?

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to use these command but failed when I run second command.
If I only run the first one,it will success to import PR2.

```
 roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
 roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
```

first terminal:

```
 [base_hokuyo_node-15] process has died [pid 32688, exit code -11].
 log files: /home/sam/.ros/log/f2be307a-c32b-11e0-98f4-20cf30a2382f/base_hokuyo_node-15*.log
 [tilt_hokuyo_node-16] process has died [pid 32691, exit code -11].
 log files: /home/sam/.ros/log/f2be307a-c32b-11e0-98f4-20cf30a2382f/tilt_hokuyo_node-16*.log
 [camera_synchronizer_node-18] process has died [pid 32693, exit code -11].
 log files: /home/sam/.ros/log/f2be307a-c32b-11e0-98f4-20cf30a2382f/camera_synchronizer_node-18*.log
```

another terminal:

```
 [ WARN] [1312965467.351520467]: The input topic '/wide_stereo/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
 [ WARN] [1312965467.351541765]: The input topic '/wide_stereo/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
 [ WARN] [1312965467.351567865]: The input topic '/wide_stereo/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10866/how-to-import-two-pr2-on-gazebo-at-the-same-time?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-25**:
pr2_empty_world.launch includes pr2.launch, so you are in effect launching some of the nodes twice, hence the errors.  You have to setup something like the multi_robot_test.launch instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [multi_robot_test.launch](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/wg_robots_gazebo/trunk/pr2_gazebo_wg/launch/multi_robot_test.launch) that works with trunk of [simulator_gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo).  It starts up 3 robots under separate ros namespaces.

I basically started with standard [pr2_empty_world.launch](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_simulator/trunk/pr2_gazebo/pr2_empty_world.launch) and namespaced nodes / added tf_prefixes.

robots spawn and pieces of it are controllable if you configure your teleop to work under a namespace, but otherwise much of this is untested.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this is enough to make it work, but you should put each pr2 that your start in its own namespace and possibly set the tf_prefix. Otherwise there will be multiple nodes with the same name (which is probably why the processes are dying).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-13**:
I'd recomment putting gazebo in the / namesapce and both PR2s in the test(1/2) namespaces and I should add that I never tried multiple PR2s in gazebo.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-13**:
I use two terminal has different namespace by `export ROS_NAMESPACE=test` and `export ROS_NAMESPACE=test2`.But when I run `roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch`and`roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch`,I got an error:Service call failed: service [/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model] responded with an error.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-10**:
Don't change any sources. The best would be to create a launch file including both in a namespace. You can try from console with environment variables ROS_NAMESPACE set first.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-10**:
What should I change? src or launch file? Is there any tutorials about this? Thank you~